# How to remove the border in jfreechart?

Tags: border, jfreechart

Hi I want to remove the border of jfreechart's chartpanel. Here is the image of that graph panel[image]

How to remove that border's little space?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `AxisOffset`

```
CategoryPlot plot =  (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setAxisOffset(RectangleInsets.ZERO_INSETS);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
plot.setInsets(new RectangleInsets(0,0, 0, 0));
//for parameter
//North,west,south,East
```